# Django Class based generic view (Createview) 'bool' object has no attribute '__dict__' error

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I've facing a problem when creating an object via CreateView (using modelform).

Code first:

View:

```
class KlientCreateView(CreateView):
form_class = KlientCreateForm
model = Klient
template_name = 'forms/klient_pridat.html'
success_url = '/thanks'
```

URLConf:

```
url(r'^klient_pridat/$', KlientCreateView.as_view(), name='url_klient_pridat'),
```

Template:

```
{% block content %}
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
<h3>formular</h3>
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
{% endblock %}    


Traceback:
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  47.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  68.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in post
  172.         return super(BaseCreateView, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in post
  138.             return self.form_valid(form)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in form_valid
  113.         return super(ModelFormMixin, self).form_valid(form)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in form_valid
  60.         return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in get_success_url
  101.             url = self.success_url % self.object.__dict__

Exception Type: AttributeError at /klient_pridat/
Exception Value: 'bool' object has no attribute '__dict__'
```

After filling the form and pushing submit, I get Error page with

```
'bool' object has no attribute '__dict__'
```

From traceback and doing some search i guess it's caused by get_success_url() method (probably by wrong 'action' in form. I experimented with that too:

```
<form action="{% url url_klient_pridat %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
OR <form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
OR <form action="/klient_pridat/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`KlientCreateForm.save` should return a `Klient` instance.

---

Right now, it's returning a `bool` (that is, `True` or `False`).

Comment: You're absolutely right! I couldn't decode the error message correctly. `KlientCreateForm save` method had `return true`, which caused the error. After changing to `return new_klient` (where `new_klient` is created upon the save method representing new object in database), everything works fine. What confuses me a little bit, that the same wrong save method worked using another `ModelForm`, where it wasn't used in class-based generic view, but processed manually in own view.

Comment: @Boun that's probably because your view wasn't using that result, but the generic one was!